# Progress dialog inside async task not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The progress dialog does not show up when the file is downloading in background. After uploading the file to the database the activity remains as it is as if nothing is happening! A progress dialog is necessary while the file is uploading.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
            Common common=new Common();
            MyTask myTask=common.new MyTask(pd);

            myTask.execute();
        }
    }
```

Asynctask:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public MyTask(ProgressDialog pd) {
        this.pd = pd;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setMessage("Uploading . . .");
        pd.show();
        pd.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //download file
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I searched all the answer of stack overflow but nothing helped me! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Share you project please??

Comment: Can you on Gmail??

Comment: you sure your async task is running, i mean try this
if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
           Log.d("check","check");
            pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
            Common common=new Common();
            MyTask myTask=common.new MyTask(pd);

            myTask.execute();
}

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Yes it executes because doInBackground is working!

Comment: maybe the file is not done uploading/downloading (hard to say which given the first two lines of your question `...file is downloading in background. After uploading the file to the database ...`

Comment: weird, this exact code is working for me, maybe your downloading task is finishing very fast

Comment: It first uploads the file to the database and then starts downloading the file. So both the thing is happening. Also uploading/downloading is working fine only the progress dialog does not work! @petey

Comment: So what should I do in that case because the activity remains as it is for few seconds and then the further actions comes up. @HarpreetSingh

Comment: [`Progress Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) is deprecated anyway, may be  you can use `progress bar` in your xml with visibility:gone, and when you are about to start download change its visilbility to visible and when it is finished set again it go gone

Answer (score 0):

[`Progress Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) is deprecated anyway, may be  you can use `progress bar` in your xml with visibility:gone, and when you are about to start download change its visilbility to visible and when it is finished set again it go gone

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank u